# Instruction Type and Count

Tags: c, memory, count, instructions

1. I need to find out the (dynamic) (assembly) instructions and count against my C program. The output I expect is similar to the following

   ```
   mov  200

   pop  130

   jne  48
   ```

   I tried `valgrind --tool=callgrind --cache-sim=yes --dump-instr=yes <my program name>` and viewed it using Kcahcegrind. I did find the instruction types but count info was no where. I would like to filter the output to discard the instructions which are due to system libraries etc.
2. I need to find out the address and the size of memory allocated using malloc in some specific functions and parts of my program. I did some heap profiling but it gives the whole heap size. Any suggestion ?
3. I want to know which memory locations are accessed by a function of my program. In other words I need to find out the memory access pattern of my program. Will counting Loads help? if yes then how can I count Loads ?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at objdump:

http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html

I'd get started with `objdump -S myprog`

Comment: @ThePosy: objdump gives static count. Which looks like              
  41c293: 4c 89 ef              mov    %r13,%rdi
  41c296: 48 c1 e6 09           shl    $0x9,%rsi
  41c29a: 48 83 ee 01           sub    $0x1,%rsi
Moreover, you can see there is no count info. Although one can write a script to help count but as stated in my question I am interested in dynamic count, which means the number and type of instructions would change depending upon the program input. Thanks